# Почему при установке ubuntu на виртуальную машину virtualbox Виснет установщик?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox

Установил Virtual box. Хочу поставить Ubuntu Desktop 22.04. Запустил установщик выбрал Try or install Ubuntu. Дальше висит черный экран и мигает курсор. В чем может быть проблема? Iso качал с официального сайта Ubuntu. Вот скрин машины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жму enter и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот Окошко virtual box:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ: в Windows 10 надо отключить Hyper-v.

Comment: а где связь-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov видимо, связь в иконке черепашки — из-за включенного hyper-v вместо виртуализации была программная эмуляция